# How to POST an Array of String with Jersey

Tags: java, arrays, http, jersey

I want to send an array of `String` directly using something like:

```
service....post(ClientResponse.class, new String[]{"one","two","three"} );
```

Is there a [`MediaType`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.18/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html) that can be used to retrieve that array of `String` on the server?

In my implementation I have a WARNING saying that **`String[]` is not resolvable to a concrete type.**

How can I POST an array without encapsulating it into another (`@XmlRootElement`) class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to return Array in Jersey REST webservice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725712/how-to-return-array-in-jersey-rest-webservice/8742821#8742821) (not exactly this, but related).

JAX-RS (nor Jersey) does not support returning List of primitive types, including String. Format is not specified, so you'll need to encapsulate your data into something and use XML/JSON (I would do that) OR you can implement your MessageBodyReader/Writer for whatever you want (even array of strings). See:

- [MessageBodyReader](http://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyReader.html)
- [MessageBodyWriter](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/javadoc/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html)

edit: JSONArray on client side:

```
ClientConfig cc = new DefaultClientConfig();
cc.getClasses().add(JSONArrayProvider.App.class);
Client c = Client.create(cc);

JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put(1);
array.put(4);

c.addFilter(new LoggingFilter());
c.resource("http://a.cz").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(array);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I am trying to POST the array as a JSONArray but do i need to implement a MessageBodyReader for JSONArrays on the server?

Comment: no, JSONArray is different case and it is supported out of the box. All you should need is to add jersey-json dependency, which contains JSONArrayProvider, which will take care of de/serializing.

Comment: I construct a JSONArray  and put a String[] and passed it to POST, but i have a ClientHandlerException : A messageBodyWriter for JSONArray and application/json type was not found.  am using org.codehaus.jettison.JSONArray.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an array like the following.  Create a Form object (basically a map - it extends MultivaluedMapImpl).  Then add the elements you want to be part of an array like it shows below.  The key to it is having the brackets [] as a suffix to the variable.  Without the brackets (at least the php rest service I was going to) thought it was simply a string and only took the last value.

```
import com.sun.jersey.api.representation.Form;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;

Form form = new Form();
form.add("myArray[]", "value1");
form.add("myArray[]", "value2");
form.add("myArray[]", "value3");

webResource.post(String.class, form);
```